# How to use .ico as image source for Context menu

Tags: c#, wpf

This problem is similar to others I have seen here, but none answer the exact question I have.
Code:

```
<Grid Background="White">
  <Grid.ContextMenu>
     <ContextMenu>
       <MenuItem Header="Test">
         <MenuItem.Icon>
              <Image Source="../Resources/cut_16.ico"></Image>
         </MenuItem.Icon> 
       </MenuItem>
     </ContextMenu>
  </Grid.ContextMenu>
</Grid>
```

cut_16.ico is in the correct format and directory and is set to "Resource" for Build Action.
The problem is that at run-time, I get a System.IO.IOException and the icon does not show up.

If I use a .png, it shows up fine, but I have an .ico I need to use.

The text for the menu does show up, however.

I have code to convert a .ico to an image source in code-behind, but I would like to do it in XAML.

Any ideas?  Thanks!!

Comment: The easy solution? Convert your .ico to a .png.

Comment: I have thought of that and will do so if there is no way to use the .ico.

Comment: Works for me if I write `<Image Source="Resources/cut_16.ico"/>`.